# Why give an array to FlatList is no working?

Tags: react-native, react-native-flatlist

I parse my data to be an array and put it into my `FlatList` but my `renderItem` function is no working.

If i change my `movieData` to be a simple array like `const movieData =[1, 2, 3, 4];` into `FlatList` it works.

So i can't figure it out why my data is no working.

Here is my `render` and `renderItem` function:

```
  renderItem = (item) => {
    console.log('renderItem =>');
    console.log(item);
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>Hi</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
render() {
    console.log('Render MainActivity=>');
    const movieData = this.props.mainMovie;
    console.log(movieData);

    return (
    <View>
      <FlatList
        data={movieData}
        renderItem={this.renderItem} 
        numColumns={1}
        horizontal={false}
        keyExtractor={(item, index) => index} 
      />
      </View>
    );
  }
```

I can see my `console.log(this.props.mainMovie);` like this, i think it is an array:
[image]

Why it is no working for renderItem ? Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

I test an array again like this:

```
const test = [{ number: '1' }, { number: '2' }, { number: '3' }];
```

[image]

It is working.

How exactly is any different with my `movieData` array ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You `renderItem` function should be like

```
renderItem = ({ item }) => {
  console.log('renderItem =>');
  console.log(item);
  return (
    <View>
      <Text>{...}</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

In your actual code, you have defined it like

```
renderItem(item)
```

The object passed to `renderItem` has a `item` property, you can access the `item` using object desctructuring like `renderItem({item})`

Hope this will help!

Comment: Hey thanks for your reply, i try it but it is still no render, it looks like the problem is still what i put the data into `FlatList` , i test another simple array update it in my question.

Comment: Can you please add the JSON of `this.props.mainMovie` into question?

Comment: I have post the `this.props.mainMovie` JSON image on my question. Is it ok ?

Comment: Yes, I can see, but I can't copy it to test, I was looking for text JSON so that I can try on FlatList.

Comment: I have no idea how to type the large JSON, but here is my API `https://obscure-reaches-65656.herokuapp.com/api?city=Taipei&theater=Centuryasia` i parse the data with my reducer.  I parse `movie` from API

Comment: I tried with the API that you have shared, and I can see the data, I think `this.props.mainMovie` contain and object which has `mainMovie` property. So, can you please try by changing `const movieData = this.props.mainMovie` to `const movieData = this.props.mainMovie.mainMovie`.

Comment: Thanks for your remind, i know what happen with my problem now `const movieData = this.props.mainMovie.mainMovie` is working.  Thank you @Prasun.